# controller in spring for form handling

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am newbie in spring. using spring 3.0 mvc.
 I am creating a spring application, I have a login form,Any one please suggest what controller i should use, as when I am using SimpleFormController its saying deprecated,

Any specific controller I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all as everybody already told you use annotation-base controller

secondly for creating a form you can use spring form taglib

thirdly you can create method like this

```
public String updateHouse(House house, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Model model) {
```

this is from my sample application. House object is auto generated from form. In my form I have fields of my House object and it is send to the method as object. @RequestParam allows me to fetch the file witch is uploaded via form (POST), Model is my view model.

As you can see it is easy :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution. I am learning Spring so want to do all the confuguration manually. i want to use multiactioncontroller but I am not sure how to take data from jsp to controller. may be it sounds basic question, please help to understand

Comment: what do you mean manualy ? anootation-based configuration is a type of configuration witch is quicker. I think that you also have a RequestParam. To take data from form you need to use either form taglib to pass on object or use RequestParam

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try [annotation-based controllers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch16s11.html)? They are easy and fun to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can try annotation based controller. Please refer below link:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html